# Unable to click on CheckBox of menu in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am not able to click on the checkBox of the menu item in Android. What is the problem in the code below?

```
<item android:id="@+id/info_tool"
    android:title="Info"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="Search" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_check"
    android:title="YOUR_TITLE"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the items in a `group` element, like this:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">

        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <group android:checkableBehavior="all">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/info_tool"
                    app:showAsAction="always"
                    android:title="Info" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Search" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_check"
                    app:showAsAction="never"
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:orderInCategory="200"
                    android:title="YOUR_TITLE"
                    android:visible="true" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </group>
</menu>
```

This answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239209/1656813) answer.